# Youtube API (with C# .NET), How can I search the monetized videos?

Tags: c#, api, video, youtube

I create a service to find the best videos on youtube who have the "monetized" option enabled.

Problem, with the basic API, I can't have this option (the monetizationDetails object is allways null).

Can you tell me how I can create this feature?

Note: I know that there is a solution because many services are able to display the monetized/not monetized information.

Thanks.